# Is there a solution in php imap, to set custom flags?

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I'm using php imap to get emails from mail server and store them in my service, I want to fetch emails from multiple email server.. and now I'm testing with gmail.
so there are many emails to receive, and I want to store body and attachments of each message..
and as you know it takes so much time!
I have to mention that I'm using `Laravel Webklex` package.

this is a part of my code for better understanding:

```
public function receiveEmails($criteria) 
{
    $client = $this->getClient();
    $folder = $client->getFolder('INBOX');
    switch ($criteria) {
       case 'ALL' :
         $messages = $folder->messages()->all()->leaveUnread()->limit(5)->get();
         break;
       case 'UNSEEN':
         $messages = $folder->query(null)->unflagged()->leaveUnread()->limit(5)->get();
         break;
    }

    return $messages;
}

/// after save emails to my server I call setFlag() function to change emails flag so next time get new emails

public function setFlag($messages)
{
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
      $message->setFlag(['flagged']);
    }
}
```

and also I tried to get messages by a limit , for example last 5 emails, or emails from last 5 days... filter by date or number..

but also I have to explain to mail server what emails I already received, to fetch another last emails.. not same emails that I already received!

my solution was to use flags... but as you know each flag have a use case in mail server, so I don't want to use default flags.. I want to use my custom flag..

but I don't know how to create a new flag and use it.
if anyone know the answer, please share it with me.. 
or if you think there is no way to define custom flag.. please share your solution for my problem.

thanks with regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP imap\_search UNSEEN SINCE date with time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698415/php-imap-search-unseen-since-date-with-time)

Comment: You linked to this question in a (now moderated away) self answer. Please vote to close as duplicate instead.

Comment: @GertArnold not a duplicate question.. but the link I mentioned.. can solve it.. in a different way.
.. I think I must mention the link in comments..

Comment: Ok, fine. Another problem is that your question isn't really answerable because you don't show code, so there's nothing for answerers to go by. So if you'd answer your own question properly it would still be an answer to an unknown problem. Next time please ask questions including a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

after change, test and debug, I solved it with this solution:

I used date of emails.. to get new emails.. by `SINCE` search criteria:

```
public function receiveEmails(string $lastDate)
{

   $client = $this->getClient();
   $folder = $client->getFolder('INBOX');

   if (empty($lastDate)) {
      $messages = $folder->query()->limit(10)->get();
   } else {
       $messages = $folder->query()->since($lastDate)->limit(10)->get();
   }

   return $messages;
}
```

so I don't need to use flags.. to get new emails,
just ask imap to return emails from `specified date` till now.. with a limit.. so don't allow imap to retrieve many messages.