# Is it possible to use PHP imap_search with NEW criteria?

Tags: php, email, imap

I am trying to use the following function, but I need filtered only the newest emails received:

```
$stream = $this->imapStream;
$emails = imap_search($stream, 'SUBJECT "B437D0CB" **NEW**');
```

The above returns an empty array instead.
When I use the UNSEEN criteria it returns me all the unread messages but I need only the ones that are received lately (they have the New label tagged on Inbox)

Comment: [The bottom of page 51](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-51) explains what SEARCH NEW does, and it may not be what you want. \Recent is almost never what anyone wants, badly supported for that reason, and about to be deprecated too.

Comment: I tried NEW but it returns an empty array always even though i have newly sent emails. I think i will figure out some work around by comparing what i had with what is added. Thank you :)

Comment: The array is empty because \recent is unsupported and/or because \recent doesn't mean what you expect it to. It doesn't mean "newly sent", for a start. It's a weird thing and best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

All the criteria that imap_search can accept are:

- ALL - return all messages matching the rest of the criteria
- ANSWERED - match messages with the \ANSWERED flag set
- BCC "string" - match messages with "string" in the Bcc: field
- BEFORE "date" - match messages with Date: before "date"
- BODY "string" - match messages with "string" in the body of the message
- CC "string" - match messages with "string" in the Cc: field
- DELETED - match deleted messages
- FLAGGED - match messages with the \FLAGGED (sometimes referred to as Important or Urgent) flag set
- FROM "string" - match messages with "string" in the From: field
- KEYWORD "string" - match messages with "string" as a keyword
- NEW - match new messages
- OLD - match old messages
- ON "date" - match messages with Date: matching "date"
- RECENT - match messages with the \RECENT flag set
- SEEN - match messages that have been read (the \SEEN flag is set)
- SINCE "date" - match messages with Date: after "date"
- SUBJECT "string" - match messages with "string" in the Subject:
- TEXT "string" - match messages with text "string"
- TO "string" - match messages with "string" in the To:
- UNANSWERED - match messages that have not been answered
- UNDELETED - match messages that are not deleted
- UNFLAGGED - match messages that are not flagged
- UNKEYWORD "string" - match messages that do not have the keyword "string"
- UNSEEN - match messages which have not been read yet

there are a lot, if you need create a new criteria well return all and apply your filter after in a loop

edit: maybe this link can help you, they want do something similar
[PHP imap_search UNSEEN SINCE date with time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698415/php-imap-search-unseen-since-date-with-time)

hope be helpful
Regards